# MapInfo Populating Dates in Table

Tags: mapinfo, import, excel, date

I am opening an Excel spreadsheet in MapInfo.

One column of the Excel spreadsheet holds a date per row. Some of the rows dont have an assigned date this is fine.

When opening the table in MapInfo, the browser window shows that these blank cells have now been infilled with the date 1899?

How can I stop this happening?

Comment: Try filling the blanks of the spreadsheet in Excel with 0 instead of leaving them blank. And just to be sure, check the dates shown in the browser of MapInfo are the same as in the spreadsheet of Excel. Sometimes data in a certain format in Excel comes out unformatted in MapInfo.

Comment: Thanks for the input. It sounds like a very sensible suggestion!